# Computing a "Double Conditional Distribution"

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, monte-carlo

This question comes in the context of Gibbs sampling, and I have posted it on the Stats Stack Exchange.

Let us say we are considering random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(X,Y)^T$, such that:
$$
(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N} \left([0,0], \begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho \\\rho & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
We sample from these distributions as follows:

Assume we have sampled $X^{(n)},Y^{(n-1)}$, then we recursively sample:

1. $Y^{(n)} \sim f_{Y|X = X^{(n)}}$ (We sample $Y^{(n)}$ from the conditional distribution given the previous sample $X^{(n)}$)
2. $X^{(n+1)} \sim f_{X|Y = Y^{(n)}}$  (We sample $X^{(n+1)}$ from the conditional distribution given the previous sample $Y^{(n)}$)

Given this sampling procedure, how can we compute the distribution of:
$$
X^{(n+1)} | X^{(n)} \quad ?
$$

That is, if we know $X^{(n)}$, how can we compute the conditional distribution of the next draw for $X^{(n+1)}$? It is easy to compute the distribution of the next draw of $X$ given the current draw of $Y$, but this draw of $Y$ depends on the previous draw of $X$.

Comment: I think in 2. where it says $X^{(n)}$ you mean $Y^{(n)}$?

Comment: Why do you say "and so on and so forth"? Doesn't the chain end there? $X^{(n)}$ fully determines the distribution of $Y^{(n)}$, and that in turn fully determines the distribution of $X^{(n+1)}$.

Comment: Yes, your comments are both right. I meant so on and so forth to highlight the recursive nature of the process - $X_5$ depends on $Y_4$ which depends on $X_3$ which depends on $Y_2$ etc.

Comment: I realize it is not the appropriate terminology - after all, this is supposed to be a Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm, so it would be wrong to suggest "long range dependencies"

Comment: If you posted it on the Stats StackExchange (CrossValidated), did anyone give you comments?  That could be helpful here.

Comment: @JimB unfortunately not, which is part of the reason why I have posted it here. I personally think the topic is more in the purview of that site, but I am wondering if I could get assistance here as this site seems more active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide details of the calculation. Essentially, we need to compute:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} | X_n]
$$
and $$
\mathrm{Var}[X_{n+1}|X_n]
$$
We know that $X_{n+1}$ conditional on $X_n$ will be normally distributed, because $X_{n+1} | Y_n$ is normal and $Y_n | X_n$ is normal (not sure if this sort of transitivity is true in general, if someone could make me aware of any details I am glossing over I would appreciate it).

Recall the very general tower property of conditional expectation, if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $G_1 \subset G_2 \subset \mathcal{F}$ are nested subalgebras, then we have that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|G_2]|G_1] = \mathbb{E}[X|G_1]
$$
for any $X$ that is in $L^1(\Omega)$. Let $G_1 = \sigma(X_n)$ and $G_2 = \sigma(Y_n)$. This satisfies the above because we generate $X_n$ first, and then generate $Y_n$. In particular, it follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|X_n] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|Y_n] |X_n] = \mathbb{E}[\rho Y_n |X_n] = \rho \cdot (\rho X_n) = \rho^2X_n
$$

For the case of the variance, we have an identity (cf. Wikipedia) that states:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\mathrm{Var}(X_{n+1}|Y_n)|X_n) = \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Var}(X_{n+1}|Y_n)|X_n] + \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|Y_n]|X_n)
$$
The conditional variance of $X|Y$ is $(1-\rho^2)$. Thus, we can finish the calculation above to get:
$$
1 - \rho^2 + \rho^2(1-\rho^2) = 1-\rho^4
$$

Thus, we arrive at:
$$
X_{n+1}|X_n \sim (\rho^2X_n, 1-\rho^4)
$$